# PhpStorm getting rid of 1 horizontal line in settings

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, nette

I`m starting to personalize my PhpStorm a bit and would love to get rid of horizontal line between PHPDoc and method while keeping the methods overall separated (with the same line)

I've been trying to make this work for several hours... help, please, help! :-D

[image: These lines]

Comment: That's line folding marks. I'm not sure if that's configurable

Comment: Those are `method separators`. You can disable them .. but that will affect both of them: the one before and after PHPDoc. Just type that name in the search box in your Settings/Preferences screen. **P.S.** I do not know why there are 2 of them. Must be related to how they work for lambdas / anon functions (the way the editor renders such lines for such functions). I personally do not like that extra line either...